# How to handle OS errors in python

Tags: python, operating-system

I am trying to create linux groups using python.Below is function for creating groups.

```
def createGroups(self):
        adminGroupCommand="groupadd "+ self.projectName+'admin'
        userGroupCommand="groupadd "+ self.projectName+'user'
        try:
            os.system(adminGroupCommand)
        except OSError as err:
            print("group already exists: "+adminGroupCommand)
        try:
            os.system(userGroupCommand)
        except OSError as err:
            print("group already exists: "+userGroupCommand)
```

The function is successfully creating groups.But if i run the same again it gives below output when run,

```
groupadd: group 'akphaadmin' already exists
groupadd: group 'akphauser' already exists
```

Its not printing my custom message  in "except"block.How can i force the function to print custom message when creating groups if they already exists.

Comment: can you do a print 'err' and tell me what it prints?

Comment: group already exists: akphaadminCommand 'groupadd akphaadmin' returned non-zero exit status 9

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say what does `print err.errno` give? Don't forgot to `import errno`

Answer (score 1):

The function `os.system` does not report errors from the command line in that way. If you're lucky you'll get the return code (that should be zero on success), but you cannot rely on that according to the documentation.

Instead the documentation recommends to use the `subprocess` module instead:

```
def createGroups(self):
    adminGroupCommand="groupadd "+ self.projectName+'admin'
    userGroupCommand="groupadd "+ self.projectName+'user'
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(adminGroupCommand, shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print("group already exists: "+adminGroupCommand)
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(userGroupCommand, shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
        print("group already exists: "+userGroupCommand)
```

The `CalledProcessError` has an attribute `returncode` that you can examine if the `groupadd` command has different return codes for different causes of failure.

Also note that `shell=True` means that you rely on the command interpreter to forward the return code (which may not always the case). Instead you could call the command directly:

```
adminGroupCommand=["groupadd", self.projectName, 'admin']
...
try:
    subprocess.check_call(adminGroupCommand)
```

...which also has the benefit that if `self.projectName` contains spaces, asterisks (or other characters that the command line interpreter might interpret) they will be sent to the command in unmodified form (as single command line argument).

Another benefit in using `subprocess` is that you can control where the output of the command is being directed. If you want to discard `stderr` or `stdout` you can redirect it to `/dev/null` without relying on a shell to do that for you:

```
subprocess.check_call(adminGroupCommand, stderr=os.devnull, stdout=os.devnull)
```

There are also possibility to redirect to `subprocess.PIPE` which allows your python code to read the standard output or standard error from the subprocess.

Comment: No doubt this time message in except block is also getting printed but still error of groupadd command is shown on shell
groupadd: group 'akphaadmin' already exists
group already exists: akphaadmin
groupadd: group 'akphauser' already exists
group already exists: akphauser

Comment: i printed the error and its:- group already exists: akphaadminCommand 'groupadd akphaadmin' returned non-zero exit status 9

Comment: @thinkingmonster Yes, without redirection the `groupadd` command will print error messages to `stderr` - with subprocess you could easily alter this behaviour to make it write to a null file instead. That way you can get rid of the error messages from `groupadd` and show your own error messages instead.